# How to save Signup form data in database(mysql) using reactjs and nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

**I have made signup form using Reactjs and want to be save emailid, password, name, address in my database(mysql) who user enter at time of signup.**

I have made connection using mysql & working fine but unable to store data of signup form.

```
var express    = require("express");
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : 'root',
database : 'myform'
});

var app = express();

connection.connect(function(err){
if(!err) {
    console.log("Database connection successful !!!");    
} else {
  console.log("Database connection failure !!!");    
}
});
app.listen(8080);
console.log('App listening at port:8080');
```

Comment: you have to create rest api for it and call from you react app using ajax and post your data there and in nodejs you have collect that data and insert into db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

**Nodejs**

```
      var mysql = require('mysql');

      var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'cccc.net',
        user: 'xxxxx_usr',
        password: 'xxxxxxx',
        database: 'name of your database goes here …'
      });

     // api here 
     app.post('/addUser', function(req, res) {
      var post = {
        srcUserID: req.body.userSrcID,
        destUserID: req.body.userid,
        messageContent: req.body.txt,
        messageSendDate: req.body.sendDate
      };

      connection.query('INSERT INTO messages VALUES ?', post, function(err, result) {
        // send response here
        res.json({msg:'success'});
      });

    });
```

you can make change in parameters

Comment: My react app is Login.js  and my mysql table is "login" with field id, Email, Password. Connection file is dbConnection.js  .. but still not working.

Comment: ` app.post('/Login', function(req, res) {
    var post = {
      id: req.body.id,
      Email: req.body.Email,
      Password: req.body.Password
    };
    console.log(req.body.Email);
    connection.query('INSERT INTO login VALUES ?', post, function(err, result) {
      // send response here
      res.json({msg:'success'});
    });

  app.listen(8080);
  console.log('App listening at port:8080');

});`

Comment: I think some setup issue occurring... let see.